# Firebase realtime database doesn't load the query result nor call onCancelled

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase realtime database doesn't load the query result nor call onCancelled method.

For the past month I've been facing a problem with database queries that seems to take forever to load.
In the production version of my app, thanks to crashylicts and firabase events i was able to detect that some sessions are not able to complete the query neither return any exception or error... the request simple "vanishes"

Since feb/march I started getting lots of complaints in google play that users were facing a "extremly long login time" and since i didnt change anything in the apps logic related to that i started monitore and look for errors

The average login time to the app is 6 seconds with 90% of the sessions being bellow 10 seconds... (ignoring the time user takes to fill the login form)
But some users would wait over 1 minute and the login wouldn't finish... these users would often get bored and close the app or try to clean data or reinstall

From what i debugged the dead end was the firebase query to the user profile.... very simple query using a previous known userid and obtaining a few persistent data from user [8 fields between strings and long... no nested data]

something like

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("any/node").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    //not called                    
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    //neither
                }
            });
```

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: If none of those two methods fires, most likely there is no internet connection on the user's device. Have you checked that out?

Comment: I'm 100% sure internet connection is ok

Comment: onFailure? where does it go?